# Make file downloadable without any file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file

I know we can make file downloadable using

```
AddType application/octect-stream .png
```

But if I have a file that dont have any extension (FileName) then how I will make that downloadable? or is there anyway to make all file downloadable within a directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this directive on your site configuration (apache2):

```
DefaultType application/octet-stream
```

And this for nginx:

```
default_type application/octet-stream;
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#defaulttype
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `.htaccess` is recommended:

```
<filesMatch "^([^.]+)$">
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
</filesMatch>
```

(This won't work with Chrome, it will append ".txt" to the filename, and it's a known bug)

This will prevent browser from showing the file content inline and let browser download it instead.

Executable file extension like .php (if you've installed), your browser will download the execution result(not the source code), is that what you want?

Comment: Actually what I want I have a file that dont have any extension, just filename like FileName, I want when my visitor click on that file, file will be download, right now its showing content, my other files have extension and all file is downloading.

Comment: @user219457 Try my new version

Comment: @user219457 Does your Apache has it's Header module enabled?